# Conditional Redirection to a URL in react

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-redux, react-router, forgot-password

I am building a "Forgot password" page. Following is the flow of my code:

1. A page with url `/auth/forgot-password` opens on clicking on Forgot Password.
2. It takes input as email and sends OTP to the registered email(if it exists in DB).
3. After sending OTP, it redirects to a new URL `/auth/new-password`.
4. Here, the remaining details are entered(ex. OTP,new password etc.)

Due to this flow, the user can access the path `/auth/new-password` by searching for it. But I don't want that to happen. User should only reach this url via `/auth/forgot-password`. User should be redirected to `/auth/forgot-password` URL if user searches for the prior one.

Currently in my Routes page I am doing this:

`<ContentRoute path="/auth/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword}/>`

`<ContentRoute path="/auth/new-password" component={NewPassword} />`

Due to some restrictions I can't change the existing flow of the code.
How can I change this to exhibit the behavior explained above?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a **HOC** (Higher Order Component).

When I want a user to authenticate before accessing a sites' page, I always create a HOC called `AuthRoute` like this.

**AuthRoute.js**

```js
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthRoute = props => {
    const { authUser, location } = props;

    if(!authUser) {
        return <Redirect to={{
            pathname: "/",
            state: { prevLoc: location.pathname }
        }} />
    }

    return <Route {...props} />;
};

function mapStateToProps({ authUser }) {
    return {
        authUser
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthRoute);
```

Then include that to the `App` component like this.

**App.js**

```js
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthRoute from './components/AuthRoute'; // AuthRoute Import
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
          {/* Include the AuthRoute component for the relevant page */}
          <AuthRoute path="/home" component={Dashboard} /> 
          <Route path="/" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

This implementation will check whether the user entered their email address on `/auth/forgot-password` page.

Completed project with HOC implementation - https://github.com/yushanwebdev/reactnd-would-you-rather